# How do I compile rust libcore for a bare-metal i386/i686 target?

Tags: rust, bare-metal

I'm trying to write some code for i686 bare metal (e.g. following https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/), but there does not appear to be a current target.  e.g. `rustc +nightly -Z unstable-options --print target-list` shows `x86_64-unknown-none` and a bunch of i686 targets, but not `i686-unknown-none`.  (I'm on a x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu host)
I have created a json target specification

```
{
  "llvm-target": "i686-unknown-none",
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-i32:32-f80:128-n8:16:32-S128-p:32:32",
  "linker-flavor": "gcc",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-pointer-width": "32",
  "target-c-int-width": "32",
  "arch": "x86",
  "os": "none",
  "executables": true,
  "panic-strategy": "abort",
  "disable-redzone": true,
  "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

I'm aware I can use `build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]` and a nightly compiler.  However my preference is to stick to stable if possible as I want this to continue to compile in future with newer rust versions.  I read up on https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/building/how-to-build-and-run.html, but it seems like overkill (and a waste of disk space) to build a whole new toolchain when the installed compiler is already capable of building for i686.

I ran `rustup component add rust-src` with only a stable toolchain installed, hoping I could compile a stable source with a stable compiler.

I tried e.g. `rustc --target ~/projects/gravel/i386.json --crate-name core --edition=2021 ~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/lib.rs --crate-type lib`, but the build failed:

```
...
error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
   --> /home/alex/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/lib.rs:179:12
    |
179 | #![feature(utf16_extra)]
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^

...
error[E0425]: cannot find function `atomic_xor` in this scope
    --> /home/alex/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/sync/atomic.rs:1875:18
     |
1875 |         unsafe { atomic_xor(self.p.get(), core::ptr::invalid_mut(val),...
     |                  ^^^^^^^^^^ help: a function with a similar name exists: `atomic_load`
...
3149 | unsafe fn atomic_load<T: Copy>(dst: *const T, order: Ordering) -> T {
     | ------------------------------------------------------------------- similarly named function `atomic_load` defined here

error: aborting due to 258 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0412, E0425, E0432, E0554.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0412`.
```

I'm guessing some things like atomic_xor might be in `compiler_builtins`, but `#![feature] may not be used on the stable release channel` looks more problematic.  I'd hoped that this might work or there might just be some unresolved symbols.

How can I compile a libcore/compiler_builtins for a bare-metal i686?  Am I on the right track or should I be doing something completely different?